# How to implement 'locate in explorer/finder' function

Tags: java, desktop-application

In a lot of programs, there is an option to locate a particular file using the native OS file explorer. How can this functionality be implemented using java?

Comment: Are you using Android, AWT, SWT, Swing, JavaFX, ...?

Comment: For swing, there's [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: I'm using javafx but should that matter? It'll be great to have a native window open up with the selected file highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java provides `java.awt.Desktop` ([API JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html)), with which such interactions can be made:

```java
File file = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file.getParentFile());
```

I use `file.getParentFile()` to open the directory containing the file, and not the file itself.
If this line is executed, Finder (on macOs), Explorer (on Windows), or the default file browser on Linux will open a new window with the specified directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about file chooser?

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("data"));
fileChooser.setInitialFileName("myfile.txt");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
 new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt")
,new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("HTML Files", "*.htm")
);
File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

More on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution to this on macos is this one:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/open", "-R", pathName);
pb.start();
```